# laravel-testing and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration

```
                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
             );
         }

        throw new QueryException(
             $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
         );
     }
 }
```

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
> PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel-testing",
> "root", Object(SensitiveParameterValue), [])

I am a beginner and new to Laravel. I am facing this error, while migrating the tables in the database.

I tried the below cmd

> php artisan migrate

But it keeps giving me error. I want to migrate successfully my file into the database. Any Suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: The error means php can reach the server via the provided address ( `127.0.0.1` ), but there is nothing listening to the given port ( `3306` ). Make sure mysql is running on your machine, and that the port is correct.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I have the Wamp server installed. but it shows an orange indication. can you tell me what is it and how to fix it? @Nicolas

Comment: There might be something preventing mysql to start, but I don't know what it is. I suggest you look into the logs and try to figure out what's going on. I can't help you more than that.

Comment: yes Wamp server has some issues in my C drive. so I have reinstalled the Wampserver in my other drive f and now it's icon turning green. thanks for the support.